# How to remove title from viewer-pdf-toolbar in Iframe?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some pdf files in my folder. When I click on the pdf I will get the file preview in the iframe. But the viewer-pdf-toolbar shows the title of a method.How I will empty the title.

```
   $("#document").html('<iframe src="@Url.Action("PreviewSelectedFile", "PDFForm", new { fileUrl = "_FilePath" }) "'.replace("_FilePath", documentName) + 'id="documentViewIframe" onload="LoadLoader();" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="overflow: auto;min-height: 550px;height: 700px;width: 100%;" ></iframe>');
```

and the preview is not working in mozilla.It gives a popup to save or open the file.
Please give some solution to my issues.

Comment: Please add mozilla version